# how to use a customised sort order in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to sort a column not by asc or desc, but I want it to sort according to the sequence that I set. for example I have this data:

```
Varchar1 |  Varchar2 | Value | Something
1401_1   | 1401_1_9  | 1     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_9  | 0     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_11 | 1     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_11 | 1     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_13 | 0     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_13 | 1     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_15 | 0     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_15 | 1     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_17 | 1     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_17 | 0     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_19 | 1     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_19 | 0     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_21 | 1     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_21 | 1     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_23 | 0     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_23 | 1     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_1  | 0     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_1  | 1     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_3  | 1     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_3  | 0     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_5  | 1     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_5  | 0     | Something2
1401_1   | 1401_1_7  | 1     | Something1
1401_1   | 1401_1_7  | 1     | Something2
```

here is my code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT TOP 12 
            [varchar2] AS [T2], 
            SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'something1' THEN value END) AS something1, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'something2' THEN value END) AS [something2] 
    FROM tbl_table 
    GROUP by [varchar2] 
    ORDER by [varchar2] DESC)x 
ORDER BY [T2] ASC
```

That code produces something like this : 1401_1_1, 1401_1_11, 1401_1_13, 1401_1_15, 1401_1_17, 
1401_1_19, 1401_1_21, 1401_1_23, 1401_1_3, 1401_1_5, 1401_1_7, 1401_1_9  ==> it sorting in varchar

I want it to sort according to this sequence : 1401_1_9, 1401_1_11, 1401_1_13, 1401_1_15, 1401_1_17, 1401_1_19, 1401_1_21, 1401_1_23, 1401_1_1, 1401_1_3, 1401_1_5, 1401_1_7

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Can you not zero pad your second and third numbers, eg 1401_01_01, 1401_01_09, etc?

Comment: Add an Order column, set it in the order you want, and sort your results by that.

Comment: @intracept Thanks for the suggestion, but I think it still do the order not like I want, for example : 01, 03, 05, 07.... I want it to be : 09, 11, ......, 01, 03.... somehing like that.

Comment: @dbugger Thanks for the suggestion dbugger. I will tried it first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
Order by PARSENAME(REPLACE(@varchar2,'_','.'),3),
         PARSENAME(REPLACE(@varchar2,'_','.'),2),
         CASE WHEN PARSENAME(REPLACE([varchar2],'_','.'),1)>=9 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
         PARSENAME(REPLACE(@varchar2,'_','.'),1)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it gives me an error : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: You must have standard format of date and must replace '_' to '-' in order to convert your field to date.

Comment: but if I sort it to date, it will be according to 1, 2, 3, 4..... something like that right?

Comment: Of course. Asc or Desc sort discretion to your Idea.

Comment: but I want it to be something like this : 9,11,13, 15,.... 1,3,5... that's the problem... I am still trying dbugger suggestion by adding another ordercolumn into the table...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56009/discussion-between-mehdi-lotfi-and-user3567963).

Comment: Thanks mehdi... I already solve it... adding another orderColumn like dBugger suggested does the trick...